# How to find failed message in websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I'm using websphere 7.0. How can I find the body of a failed message ?
 I can see a failed event generated for the message but not able to see the message body.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using WebSphere Application Server.

For this (again assuming that is what you are looking for...) I would put the HTTP plugin in trace mode in a test system and reproduce the problem.  This trace shows you EVERYTHING that is going on at the request level to and from WAS.

If my answer is not related to your question, do not hesitate to clarify.

Nic.

Comment: Thanks Nic for your reply.I'm using Websphere App server.I have also installed ESB in it. I can see failed events in app server at : Integration Application > Failed Event Manager > Get all failed events ; but it not showing the message payload (I can see message properties). One more thing to add, All my messages are JMS message.